# The system cannot find the path specified os.listdir in python

Tags: python, listdir

```
dirs= os.listdir('C:/Users/DELL PC/Desktop/Msc Project/MSc project/dataset')
for file in dirs:
    print (file)

lowfiles  = [f for f in os.listdir('Training data/LOW') 
             if os.path.isfile(join('Training data/LOW', f))] 
highfiles = [f for f in os.listdir('Training data/HIGH')
             if os.path.isfile(join('Training data/HIGH', f))]
files = []
```

I am running this code to create feature vectors but it is showing

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'Training data/LOW'
```

While when I run the first few code to show me the directory it is showing all the files in the directory.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you in the directory where `Training data/LOW` exists when you run your Python program?

Comment: Python is looking for the directory `'/Training data/Low'` from the current path you are executing from.

Comment: What is `join` here? You should use `os.path.join`. And if "Training data" is in "C:/Users/DELL PC/Desktop/Msc Project/MSc project/dataset", you should prepend the full path.

Comment: you need to take care of space between Training and data. In unix you need to put "Training data" between quotes.

Comment: @RishiBansal You don't need to add quotes in Python in such a case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. In such cases I prefer to write an auxiliary function rather than repeatedly type (almost) the same long line (too error-prone). Likewise, if the list comprehension gets too long, I prefer the loop form.

```
import os

def files(path):
    result = []
    for name in os.listdir(path):
        fullname = os.path.join(path, name)
        if os.path.isfile(fullname):
            result.append(name)
    return result

path = r"C:\Users\DELL PC\Desktop\Msc Project\MSc project\dataset"
for file in os.listdir(path):
    print(file)

lowfiles = files(os.path.join(path, r"Training data\LOW"))
highfiles = files(os.path.join(path, r"Training data\HIGH"))
```

---

To clarify the comment below: the following will enter an infinite loop that prints 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3...

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
for i in a:
    a.append(i)
    print(i)
```

Never add elements to a container on which you are doing a loop.

Here you are trying to do this:

```
for i in lowfiles:
    lowfiles.append([i, 'Low'])
```

So if `lowfiles` initially contains `["file1", "file2"]`, then after the first loop it will be `["file1", "file2", ["file1", "Low"]]`, then `["file1", "file2", ["file1", "Low"], ["file2", "Low"], [["file1", "Low"], "Low"], ...]`. You don't want to do that.

I am only guessing, but it you want to rename your files by appending "Low" at the end of the name, then:

First modify the function `files` above to append the `fullname` (with directory) rather than only the `name` without the directory), so that you don't have to `os.path.join` again and again.

To rename files do the following:

```
for fullname in files(os.path.join(path, r"Training data\LOW")):
    os.rename(fullname, fullname + "Low")
```

If there is a file extension you don't want to change, you can do this:

```
for fullname in files(os.path.join(path, r"Training data\LOW")):
    base, ext = fullname.rsplit(".", 1)
    os.rename(fullname, base + "Low." + ext)
```

And if you don't want to renames files, you will have to clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I tried with your code and it is reading the folder but the next issue I am having is I am getting into a loop where the lowfile is made, 
So it keeps appending it with 'Low'.   
The same is then wrong with the files but I am never getting out of the first loop:         
  for i in lowfiles:
    lowfiles.append([i, 'Low'])  What should I do now?

Comment: @vandana Don't append to `lowfiles` in a loop on `lowfiles`. Python will indeed never stop this. What are you trying to do? Do you want to *rename* the files? Here `lowfiles` is a list of strings, but you are adding elements that are lists (of two strings). Not what you want, whatever it may be.

Comment: I have a csv file and had applied some feature extraction and wants it gives back the result in a new csv named as features.csv                                                                                                 

mypath = 'Training-Data/'
csvfile = "Features/features.csv"

with open(csvfile, "a") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerow(names) 
    
    subfolder =  files[counter][1]
    tag = files[counter][1] 
    data_path = mypath + subfolder +'/'+files[counter][0]

Comment: @vandanaNot sure I understand. Do you want to concatenate several csv files? Here what you are writing will write file *names* to a csv file. Is it what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, tried several solutions that never worked until i got this one - maybe you can remove the for-loop section?:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r'C:\DRO\DCL_rawdata_files' # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

li = []
for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```